# BarLegend changes in Version 10

Tags: legending, version-10

Apparently, `BarLegend` in version 10 displays tick legends in scientific notation when they are smaller in magnitude than 0.01.  For instance,

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-.015, .015}}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, FontSize -> 12]]
```

creates the object

[image]

How can I change the tick labels to decimal notation, as they would have appeared in version 9?

By the way, the `Bold` directive evidently is being ignored.  Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: Just had a look at examples in the docs and `LabelStyle` looks very buggy. You shouldn't need to explicitly use `FontSize`, the number should be sufficient -- but it is not. As you say `Bold` is not recognised, nor is `FontWeight->Bold`.

Comment: Seems to work OK in 10.0.1

Comment: @Sjoerd Confirmed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Two work-arounds:

**(1)** Use `TickLabels`

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-0.015, 0.015}}, ImageSize->300,
  Charting`TickLabels -> 
  (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity, 3}],Bold,Black,12] & /@ Range[-.015, .015, .005])]
```

[image]

**(2)**  Use `LabelingFunction`:

```
BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {-0.015, 0.015}}, ImageSize->300, 
    LabelingFunction -> (Style[NumberForm[#, {Infinity,3}],Bold, Black,12] &)]
(* same picture *)
```

Note: Just to make the labels `Bold` the option combination `BaseStyle->Directive[Bold,12], LabelStyle->Black` also works.

Comment: Despite the fact that Mathematica flags `ImageSize`, `BaseStyle`, `LabelingFunction`, and ``Charting`TickLabels`` as unknown option names, both of your recommendations work well.  Thanks, @kguler.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thank you for the accept.

Comment: Version 10.0.1 appears to resolve the issues described above.