# Does PlotLegend lie in a figure?

Tags: legending

I wonder if `PlotLegends` is part of a figure. Indeed in the code

```
Show[
 Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Black}, {"Sin"}]],
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red}, {"Cos"}]],
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "LM Roman 10"}
 ]
```

it does not seem to be affected by `BaseStyle` and not shown in the exported figure.

Is that a bug or am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: The short answer is **no**. If you make a plot with legends and type `Head[%]`, it will say `Legended` instead of `Graphics` or `Graphics3D` etc.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to your question is, it depends.  If the legend is placed inside the area of the graphic, then the graphic, including the legend, can be highlighted and saved by right-clicking and choosing `Save Graphics As...`

[image]

The code used to produce this graphic is

```
Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> {Black, Red}, 
    PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Sin, Cos}, 
            LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Magneto"}], {.6, .8}], 
    BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Goudy Stout"}]
```

Note that the `LineLegend` uses the `FontSize` from the plot `BaseStyle`, but not the `FontFamily`.  Consequently, it must be specified separately, as shown.  I used two distinctive fonts, so that their difference would be obvious. (I do not have the *LM Roman 10* font.)  More generally, `LineLegend` has many options that can be used to create stylized legends.

Comment: Actually, you're not using "LM Roman 10" neither for the axes nor for the legends. Do you have that font or your solution is not working?

Comment: @Fabio  Good point.  I do not have that font.  Also, the legend is ignoring the `FontFamily` in `Baseline`, even though it is not ignoring the `FontSize`.  I shall give this more thought.

Comment: @Fabio  To specify the legend font, it appears necessary to use `PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{Sin5, Cos}, LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Magneto"}], {.6, .8}]`  I used a distinctive font here, so that I would be sure that it changed.  I shall edit it into my answer soon.  Thanks for catching this issue.

Comment: I had the same conclusion, but still I' still convinced that BaseStyle should be inherited by all of the text in a plot.

Comment: @Fabio  Version 10 introduced a number of formatting bugs in `PlotLegends`.  Perhaps, not all of them have been corrected.  See, for instance, my earlier [question 55150](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55150/1063).

Answer (score 2):

I always had problems with that. I use `Export` and the expression in order to get the legend in the exported figure.

```
plot = Show[
  Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Black, 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Black}, {"Sin"}]], 
  Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 2 π}, PlotStyle -> Red, 
   PlotLegends -> LineLegend[{Red}, {"Cos"}]], 
  BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "LM Roman 10"}]

Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "fig.png", plot]
```

[image: plot]